# Replace all instances of a sequence in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to replace all instance like

**{IMAGE:imagename}** with **imagepath** ,

**{MESSAGE:messagename}** with **message**.

I tried using replaceAll function of string class but not able to achieve the same.

**Example code :**

```
String str = "HELLO WORLD {IMAGE:abcd}";
str = str.replaceAll("{IMAGE:abcd}", "defg");
```

**Output :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{IMAGE:abcd}
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:2775)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1889)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2189)
    at com.example.WorkSheet.main(WorkSheet.java:28)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{` is a regex metacharacter and should be escaped, try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\{IMAGE:abcd}", "defg");
```

note that it is enough to escape `{`, regex compiler will understand that `}` is used as a regular character.

Answer (score 0):

`{` and `}` are special characters used in regular expression to mark repititions. Try escaping them with `\\` or use `Matcher.quoteReplacement("{IMAGE:abcd}")`, which escapes all special characters.

Answer (score 0):

The `replaceAll` method takes parameters as `replaceAll(String Regex, String replacement)` where `Regex` is supposed to be a Regular Expression. So you might want to use:

```
str.replaceAll("\\{IMAGE:abcd}","defg");
```

instead of

```
str.replaceAll("{IMAGE:abcd}", "defg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the character "{", as shown below :

```
public class A{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "HELLO WORLD {IMAGE:abcd}";
    str = str.replaceAll("\\{IMAGE:abcd\\}", "defg");
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try.

```
 str = str.replaceAll("\\{IMAGE:abcd\\}", "defg");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class A
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String str = "HELLO WORLD {IMAGE:abcd}";
str = str.replaceAll("\\{IMAGE:abcd}", "defg");
    System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```